# "pkexec /usr/bin/gdb" returns error "not authorized"

Tags: linux, gdb, sudo

I want to start gdb with root rights (I use Visual Studio Code and want to start gdb as root because the application I want to debug requires root). In a terminal, I type:

`pkexec /usr/bin/gdb`

A graphical window opens where I enter the user (user15) and the su password.

An error message is displayed:

`Error executing command as another user: Not authorized`

Why doesn't pkexec let me start gdb as root?

/var/log/auth.log:

```
May 17 15:24:59 computer polkit-agent-helper-1[11775]: pam_unix(polkit-1:auth): conversation failed
May 17 15:24:59 computer polkit-agent-helper-1[11775]: pam_unix(polkit-1:auth): auth could not identify password for [user15]
May 17 15:24:59 computer polkitd(authority=local): Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-session:8 (system bus name :1.140, object path /org/lxqt/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
May 17 15:24:59 computer polkitd(authority=local): Operator of unix-session:8 FAILED to authenticate to gain authorization for action org.freedesktop.policykit.exec for unix-process:9764:310891 [/bin/bash] (owned by unix-user:user15)
May 17 15:24:59 computer pkexec[11771]: user15: Error executing command as another user: Not authorized [USER=root] [TTY=/dev/pts/3] [CWD=/home/user15] [COMMAND=/usr/bin/gdb]
May 17 15:24:59 computer polkitd(authority=local): Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:8 (system bus name :1.144 [/usr/bin/lxqt-policykit-agent], object path /org/lxqt/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
```

The user is inside the sudo group:

```
computer:~$ groups
user15 adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

Here is /etc/sudoers:

```
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Comment: I don't think `pkexec` has anything to do with `/etc/sudoers`. Try using `sudo` instead (or set up an appropriate policykit policy).

Answer (score 0):

You need to establish a policy kit - look into here:

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=127716